# Horizontal connection between plates

Tags: building, connections

If I only have minimum height available (one plate), how can I make a horizontal connection between two components? I need the connection to be easily disconnectable yet sturdy (like technic bricks with grey connectors).

I thought about hinge plates ([4276](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/4276a)/[4275](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/4275a)), but they are far too tight. I don't own any of the old ones ([x1125](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/x1125)/[x1126](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/x1126)), so I cannot check myself, but are they less tight?

Clarification - the components are built regularly (studs up), and sit next to each other and should be moved horizontally to separate or reconnect them.

There's no such thing as [2921](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/2921) but only one plate high? I'd use that together with [4085](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/4085b), that would be perfect.

Comment: question: do your components sit RIGHT next to each other or is there a gap?

Comment: ...was just wondering as two clips will be three studs wide, and if this layer is only one plate high how would you offset the clip?

Comment: @Uli right next to each other, yes, with slope bricks on top the "connection zone", and 2466s to the sides, so no possibility to add more space, I fear, without making the interior look ugly. If everything fails, I'll have to make the "roof" removable instead, but that will make the whole thing a lot less rigid.

Comment: so basically this is about two buildings touching each other with plain walls, each wall one stud width, can't use technic bricks because of visibility on inside, trying to hide clips in ceiling layer... right? any picture would certainly help : )

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Mr. Blue and Ms. Red live next doors. Their houses are simple. The walls are one stud wide, the ceiling's one plate thick, some slopes on the roof.

[image]

Now they want to move their houses wall to wall. Mr. Blue bores a hole into the wall and happily bolts in a big peg. But Ms. Red thinks that's just a big eyesore!

So they try to hide some clips in the ceiling, but as it turns out...

[image]

...they leave a gap one stud wide.

And they don't fit onto a stud. They need at least one more layer of plates in the ceiling.

[image]

Okay. That's how I understand the situation. You cannot use Technic bricks (one can see them on the inside), your ceiling's height is just one plate.

So, why not go **on top** of the ceiling? **Up onto the roof**, between the slopes and hide some clips or hinges in a chimney or under an antenna?

Just two ideas, the yellow plates represent your ceiling layer.

[image]

Fun fact: here the amount of clutch depends on the length of the blue antenna's tip; slide it up to adjust.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried horizontal clips? They will be a little taller than 1 plate in the center, but you might be able to adapt them to your needs given that the connection point is just one plate. Perhaps these parts:

[60470b](https://rebrickable.com/parts/60470b/plate-special-1-x-2-with-clips-horizontal-open-o-clips/)

[image: 60470b]

[48336](https://rebrickable.com/parts/48336/plate-special-1-x-2-side-handle-closed-ends/71/)

[image: 48336]

Something like [4623](https://rebrickable.com/parts/4623/plate-special-1-x-2-with-arm-up-horizontal-arm-6mm/71/) with a vertical clip might also be a possibility depending on your constraints:

[image: 4623]

Answer (score 2):

You've already been given a number of solutions, where the part that actually goes within the components is only one plate high, while the actual connection is a bit more. I can't do any better, but I want to suggest another option:

A combination of
[image: Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Tow Ball on End]
or 
[image: Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Tow Ball on Side]

With either
[image: Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Small Tow Ball Socket on End]
or
[image: Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Small Tow Ball Socket on Side]

The right combination of these parts allow some offset (if the parts fit), and these also allow movement in more than one direction.

Answer (score 2):

How about trying [Hinge Vehicle Roof Holder 1 x 4](https://rebrickable.com/parts/4315/hinge-vehicle-roof-holder-1-x-4/) with [Hinge Train Gate 2 x 4](https://rebrickable.com/parts/2873/hinge-train-gate-2-x-4/)?[image]  [image]

Their connection is a lot looser (at least for old parts) than the 1x2 finger plate hinges.

Comment: Historical pieces phased out more than a decade ago ...

Answer (score 1):

Modern hinges, like below, may give you desired result.

Here are [Hinge Plate 1 x 2 Locking with 2 Fingers on Side](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60471) and [Hinge Plate 1 x 2 Locking with 1 Finger on Side with Bottom Groove](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=44567a)

[image][image]